# What's the time complexity for Sorted Array, Sorted Linked List and Binary Search Tree in Best Case for Insertion, Deletion

Tags: arrays, sorting, time-complexity, big-o, binary-search-tree

What's the time complexity for Sorted Array, Sorted Linked List and Binary Search Tree in Best Case for Insertion, Deletion(and why?). Also, how do people usually determine the best case from an algorithm. I understand how to determine the worse case from an algorithm, for example a for loop will be O(n). So far, I only have found average and worse case online, none of them shows the best case.

Comment: Best case isn't very useful because it's often based on luck. IE: every insertion and deletion is found in the first place you look.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you consider as best case. For example if I consider best case as "insert unique element/delete unique element" all of tree structure take O(1) time.
In this case I think there aren't best cases because

1. In Sorted Array an Linked List you have to find the position where insert the new element O(n), then you have to shift other elements (O(n) in array, O(1) in linked lists), same complexity for deletion
2. In Binary Search Trees, insertion/deletion operations takes all O(h) time, where h is the tree height. If your tree is balanced (AVL or Red-Black trees), h = O(log n), so the complexity become O(log n)

In this case the big-O notation describe all cases.

P.S. In general best cases aren't considered so much, because they are already considered in medium case.